# Successive circle in 2D array in C with Bresenham's circle algorithm

Tags: c, arrays

I return back with another dummy question as I'm newbie. I wrote a code in c to fill a 2D array using Bresenham's algorithm. The codes fill 2D array with successive circles with:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{
    double *v;
    int i;
    v = (double*)malloc(101*101*sizeof(double));

    for(i=0;i<101*101;i++)
    {
        v[i]=0.0;
    }


    for(i=0;i<73;i++)
    {
        draw_circle(v, 101,101,51,51,i,(double)i);
    }
    write_arraya(v,"test.txt",101,101);
    free(v);
    
    return 1;
}
```

which used Bresenham's algorithm

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
void draw_circle (double *v, int m, int n, int xr, int yr, int radius, double value)
{
    int x, y;
    int l;

    l = (int) radius * cos (M_PI / 4);

    for (x = 0; x <= l; x++)
    {
        y = (int) sqrt ((double) (radius * radius) - (x * x));

        set_value (v, m, n, xr+x-1, yr+y-1, (double)value);
        set_value (v, m, n, xr+x-1, yr-y-1, (double)value);
        set_value (v, m, n, xr-x-1, yr+y-1, (double)value);
        set_value (v, m, n, xr-x-1, yr-y-1, (double)value);

        set_value (v, m, n, xr+y-1, yr+x-1, (double)value);
        set_value (v, m, n, xr+y-1, yr-x-1, (double)value);
        set_value (v, m, n, xr-y-1, yr+x-1, (double)value);
        set_value (v, m, n, xr-y-1, yr-x-1, (double)value);
        printf("x= %d, y=%d\n", x, y);
    }
}
```

and setting values by:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

void set_value (double *v, int m, int n, int i, int j, double value)
{
    if(i>=0 && i<m && j>=0 && j<n)
    {
        v[i*n+j]=(double)value;
    }
}
```

and write them to a text file with

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void write_arraya(double *v, char file_name[], int row, int col)
{
    FILE *fp;
    int i, j;

    fp = fopen(file_name, "w");

    for(i=0;i<row;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<col;j++)
        {
            fprintf(fp,"%e ",v[i*col+j]);
        }
        fprintf(fp,"\n");
    }

    fclose(fp);
}
```

these are works properly but the main question is about unfilled elements in array. There are some elements remains with zero values. I would like to fill these values with a proper value. Note that the speed of code is important for me so any other suggestion is wellcome. Is there any idea?
I attached the fig I observed from text file

[image: The filled 2D array]

The dark blue pixels (mostly black) are unfilled element in array

Comment: Where's size of v and where's memory allocation for v?

Comment: This looks familiar. Are you sure this isn't supposed to happen?

Comment: "I would like to fill these values with a proper value." --- Which would be...? Bresenham circles with successive integer radii won't necessarily hit all pixels inside the big circle.

Comment: The proper value means that the gradient continuously should be happened in my problem. I need it to distributing some coefficients radially around a defined center

Comment: @zubergu - probably a good time to refresh the memory by reading the documentation. If you ask for 100 bytes, you get 100 bytes. If you want strlen("some string") + 1 bytes, then that's what you ask for.

Comment: Then Bresenham is probably the wrong choice.

Comment: If Bresenham is wrong then what do you suggest?

Comment: Go over each cell and calculate its distance to the center.

Comment: I told that the speed is very important to me. I need this for a real-time data processing. I should calculate sum of 50 2d array and find the maximum after a large matrix multiplication using cblas. the mentioned code is just part of my code. All code should be run in less than 1 seconds. Now let me know is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: @RezaMN - we've got no idea of the complexity of your other code, much less the time it takes to execute. There's also a glaring omission of the hardware you intend to run this code on. There's a big difference between (say) an i7 and a Raspberry Pi. I suggest you concentrate on better defining your requirements for this particular component of the solution. Using sqrt per pixel can be plenty fast. I've got a 128x128 16bit circular image using sin for every pixel, being redrawn about once every second  and a half - on a 16MHZ Atmega 328p microcontroller.

Comment: The holes appear because you are drawing only circle *outlines*. There is no guarantee that your integer-only circles touch each other at every pixel. One perfect solution would be to *fill* each circle, drawing from largest to smallest. However, since you say you need speed, try slightly fatter lines: draw one or two extra pixels. You'll have to experiment to see which ones, and how much, you need.

Comment: Footnote: this is definitely *not* "Bresenham's" algorithm. B's algorithm for calculating the 8 octant coordinates is all-integer and doesn't use π, `cos` and `sqrt`: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm

Comment: Instead of `y = (int) sqrt...` you'd rather use rounding - will eliminate the weird cross in the middle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An **inelegant** way would be to draw 2 (or if needed 3) different circles for every possible radius, but a slightly different center point (one for x,y an other for x+1, y). - In this case your array must be big enough to handle the shifted circles (have an additional column).

A much **nicer** solution would be not to draw circles at all. Just iterate through the pixels, get their distance from center (using the Pythagorean theorem, which is already utilized in your code), then calculate the color based on the distance. - You can optimize this to do only one quarter of the area. And further optimize to do only one eighth.